# Evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|}\cos(y^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|}\cos(y^2)$$

I have tried the following paths:
$$(x,kx),(x,kx^2),(ky,y)$$ and I get that the limit is $0$ but according to WA [there is not limit](https://goo.gl/Ewvgql), how should I approach this?

Comment: Please replace "there is not limit" by "according to WA, there is no limit" or some similar formulation.

Comment: Isn't this simply because woflram/maple and other similar systems by default operate in complex numbers? Although I am not sure how this result would differ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $0 \le \frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|}|\cos(y^2)| \le \frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|} \le |x|$

Hence

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2}{|x|+|y|}\cos(y^2)=0$$

Comment: But https://goo.gl/Ewvgql

Comment: Wolfram is not the bible

Comment: @gbox I seem to remember there exists some kind of compendium of WA queries leading to absurd answers. You might want to add the present one to the list, if it is not already there.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2=|x|^2\leq |x|^2+2|x|\cdot |y|+|y|^2=(|x|+|y|)^2 .$

$$\text {So }\quad \left|\; x^2\cos (y^2)/(|x|+|y|)\;\right|\leq \left|\; (|x|+|y|)^2\cos  (y^2)/(|x|+|y|)\;\right|=$$ $$=\left|\;|x|+|y|\;\right|\cdot |\cos (y^2)|\leq |x|+|y|$$ which goes to $0.$